# Where to store user images on Jhipster with Angular

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

What is the best practice upload user images and how can i do?

Should I store it as a imageUrl in the jhi_user table and save the image in the *"src/main/webapp/content/images"* folder? (If I do this it could be destroy with the redeploy)
What is the purpose of the imageUrl column?

Or should I store it as base64 in database column? (If I do it this way; should I add a new blob column to the "jhi_user" or "userExtra" table).

Or external folder?

Or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user can upload images at runtime, it 's impossible to store them in `src` because images in `src` are packaged into your JS bundle by webpack at build time.

Simplest approach would be to create a `UserPicture` entity with a blob field to store the image and a relationship with `User` entity because JHipster would generate almost all code.

Comment: What is the purpose of the imageUrl column?

Comment: It's mainly used for OIDC authentication where the user profile is managed in an external identity provider like KeyCloak or Okta (outside your application).